# Hidden div isn't showing on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a simple registration with javascript cheking stuff on the same site. I have a problem with a hidden DIV that's supposed to show when the user clicks on password input, it doesn't show.  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wy2Lkscp/

This is the javascript part

```
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {

var pswd = $(this).val();

//pass lenght
if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
  $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
  $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}

//capital letter
if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
    $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//number
if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
    $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

}).focus(function() {
$('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
$('#pswd_info').hide();
});
```

And the html :

```
<form class="form" action="http://google.com" method="post">
    <label name="nick">Nick:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> <br>
     <label name="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email"/> <br>       
    <label name="pass">Heslo:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pswd" name="pswd" />
<div id="pswd_info">
      <h4>Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>
      <ul>
          <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
          <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
          <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <br>
```

And the pswd class :

```
#pswd_info {
    width:220px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#fefefe;
    font-size:.875em;
    border-radius:20px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px #ccc;
    border:1px solid #ddd; 
    display:none;
}
```

And in the head :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no `<input>` in your html..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wy2Lkscp/  this is your code in fiddle .. update it

Comment: Damn, I forgot, thanks. @JCOC611

Comment: <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> <br>
you target "text" instead of "password". change and it will work (http://jsfiddle.net/p941u1jr/) tnx to Mohamed

Comment: Actually, it works [just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/wy2Lkscp/1/) with the html provided...

Comment: after update the code in fiddle click on update button and then post the new link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. Please check your input selector or input name at the end input exist.

Or just add below appropriate section of your page:

```
<input type="password" name="yourname">
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a differnet problem, a mistake on my side. 
The $(document).ready(function() { didnt cover the whole script. Sorry for wasting your time.